# Detect someone hooking onto a window handle

Tags: .net, security, window-handles

Can you detect if someone is trying to hook into a window handle of your application (or a part thereof) in .NET?

Comment: Do you mean a subclass or a windows hook?

Comment: This is probably going to be a very complicated topic.  There are actual companies which only do this [Game hack-shield developers]... Definately gonna bookmark this and see what comes up.